# STM 8 register addresses

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, stm8

My question has to do with how STM8 microcontrollers address things. Maybe Im missing something, I wrote a small program where the problem exists. The weird thing is that its different on my computer vs the stm8 MCU.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define START_ADDRESS *(unsigned char*)0x1001

void printAddress(unsigned char * address){
    printf("The address inside the function: %p\n",address);
}
int main()
{
    printf("The address outside function: %p\n",&START_ADDRESS);
    printAddress(&START_ADDRESS);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this function on my computer is as expected the addresses match.

output:

> The address outside the function: 0x1001
>
> The address inside the function: 0x1001

output on the STM8 mcu:

> The address outside the function: 0x0110
>
> The address inside the function: 0x0110

So my question is why does it do this, where is it happening and if I write to the START_ADDRESS register is it writing at 0x1001 or 0x0110? It might just be that the printf on both systems is slightly different.

Comment: What would it print for `*(unsigned char*)0x0110`? Can you try casting it to `void*`? `%p` is for `void*` not for `unsigned char*` `%p\n", (void*)address);` and `%p\n", (void*)&START_ADDRESS);` What compiler are you using? What would it print for `for (unsigned i = 1; i < 0x10000ul; i *= 2) printf("%p\n", (void*)(uintptr_t)i);` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk Nice idea for the questioner to check! -- But, in C every pointer is compatible with `void*`. -- However, it looks like an endianness problem, but I'm not sure, why the STM8 compilers works like this.

Comment: `But, in C every pointer is compatible with void*` - Accessing any memory using `char*` pointer is allowed, but that does not matter. What matters, is that `%p` printf format specifier expects `void*` argument - passing argument of different type is technically undefined behavior.

Comment: STM8 is big endian I believe, so the explanation is related to that. However, it should have the same endianess for 16 bit data and 16 bit addresses, so I can't explain it. Though obviously `int main() { return 0; }` will go haywire on any bare metal MCU.

Comment: Disregard the main ```int main() { return 0; }``` that was just the example I placed on the computer. I tried to cast it as a ```void*``` but I had the same result. Ive come to the conclusion that the actual address is 0x1001 but not sure why the ```%p``` changes that.

Comment: @thebusybee - Great observation to recognize endianess, I had missed this when reading the question. To verify, what about trying out 0x1002 instead :-)